# How to delete an image from the database in django

Tags: python, django, database, python-imaging-library

I have a database that contains images as posts and want the functionality, for images in the database to get deleted once the post gets deleted. I am using the pillow module to handle images in the database. Is there any way I could do that?

In my models.py this is the code I use to save images. Just in case it was needed

```
def save(self):
    super().save()
    img = Image.open(self.picture.path)
    width, height = img.size
    ratio = width/height
    if img.height > 500:
        outputsize = (500, (height/ratio))
        img.thumbnail(outputsize)
        img.save(self.picture.path)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since the best method so far is that you could first do

> pip install django-cleanup

Then in your settings.py add,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 ...
'django_cleanup', # should go after your apps)
```

This would do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions that might work:

```py
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # You have to prepare what you need before delete the model
    storage, path = self.image.storage, self.image.path
    # Delete the model before the file
    super(Profile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
    # Delete the file after the model
    storage.delete(path)
```

Add it to the model which you want the image to be deleted from. **Or**:

```py
Model.objects.get(id=obj_id).photo.delete(save=True)
```

Substitute obj_id, photo, and Model to instances that you deem necessary. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete)

Still, there are more solutions on other threads. Look up "Django delete filefield" and you'll find longer solutions if my proposals don't work.

Comment: Nop both models  didn't work but there is an easier method which can be done, we should "pip install django-cleanup" and add it to the installed apps

Comment: Anyways thanks a lot for your time and effort in attempting this question